# Change of variables in double integral with same limits

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

I have the following integral
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(y-1)^3}{(a(x-1) x y +b (y-1))^2} dx dy
$$

and I know that this integral can also be expressed as

$$
2\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x^3 y^3 (x-1)}{(a(x-1) (y-1) -b x (1-xy))^2}  dx dy
$$

I need to find a change of variables that transforms one into the other.

**Comments**:
To keep the same limits of integration, this type of change of variables work
$$
x\to (1-x')^n ~,~~y\to (1-y')^n
$$

However, I think that the needed change of variables involves both variables, such as
$$x\to f(x',y')$$ $$y\to g(x',y')$$, and then, with what I have tried, I do not recover the same limits. Any suggestion, or comment about where to start would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The factor $2$ before the integral suggests that you probably got $\int_{-1}^1 \operatorname{evenfunction}(u)$ for some substitution in $u$.

Comment: This system $\begin{cases}(v-1)uv=(x-1)(y-1)\\(v-1)=-x(1-xy)\end{cases}$ is solvable in $(u,v)$ and translates one denominator to the other, however it seems complicated to determine the range for $u$. Note that replacing first line by $(u-1)uv$, which looks more natural according to a correspondence $u\mapsto x$ and $v\mapsto y$, does not work so well, both $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ are unsolvable (i.e implicit). I do not see other possibilities though, so I guess it worth a try...